# SQLAlchemy - Right way to "double queries"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

please what is right way for this simple model?

I have two models: Subject and Report:

```
class User(UserMixin, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(db.String(60), unique=False, nullable=True)
    ...
    reports = db.relationship('Report', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

class Report(UserMixin, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reports'
    ...
    created_at = Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.now)
    user_id = Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

and i need list of all Users with date of last Report.

Dirty way is:

```
subjects = User.query.all()
for s in subjects:
    report_date = Report.query.filter(Report.subject_id == s.id).order_by(Report.id.desc()).first()
    print('Subject + Report', s.email, report_date)
```

Please how to create this list in clean way?

(e.g. join tables and query, temporary table with IDs of Subjects + date of last visit, store last visits date directly to table Subject ...)

Thanks.

Comment: To you how to join queries in sql/sqlachemy?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This is a common type of question and you should have a look around the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Comment: @Ilja thank you for answer. I am using SQL DBMS (specifically MySQL / SQLAlchemy). Please, can you give me more information (or example)? I don't have experiences with this type of model.

Comment: Please take a look at [Correlated Subquery Relationship Hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid) of the official documentation. Create a hybrid property (with the `.expression` version) from the example, replacing `sum` with `max` and adding `order_by(...)`. Then you can query both: `q = session.query(User, User.latest_report_date)` and `q` will return tuples of form `(User, date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what you really need but if it's to access the last report for each other of a list, you just have to do:

```
last_report = user.reports.order_by(Report.created_at.desc()).first()
```

You could had it has a property or an hybrid_property to your User model:

```
@property
def last_report(self):
    return user.reports.order_by(Report.created_at.desc()).first()

@property
def last_report_date(self):
    return self.last_report.created_at
```

And to get a list of tuple containing email and report_date, you could do that:

```
db.session.query(User.email, func.max(Product.created)).join(Report).group_by(Provider.email).all()
```

Anyway, if you have a lot of entries and you want to show this list to web users, you should think to use a pagination. Flask-sqlalchemy provide an easy way to do it.

Comment: thank you for answer. My list of users has 15k lines and every user has created cca 1000 reports. Print of all users with dates of last reports take cca 18 seconds. I looking for something little bit more efficient (if it exist of course :) )

Comment: Could you write me the tuple you would like for each element of your list ? Something like: [(email, report_date)] ?